# Why does spark UI at port 18080 say "cluster mode" when I launched in client mode in the config file?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

In my `spark-defaults.conf` file I have the following line:

```
spark.master=yarn-client
```

Now, I launch a job, and I look at the spark UI (which is at `<master ip address>:18080`) and I see the following at the top of the page:

```
REST URL: spark://<master ip address>:6066 (cluster mode)
```

I restarted all of the spark workers and spark master, and distributed the `spark-defaults.conf` file to all of the spark workers/slaves.
I cannot tell if this is running in cluster mode or client mode?  And why is my setting not getting picked up by the spark UI?

Comment: Care to share the exact job launch command & arguments?

Comment: I figured out that (cluster mode) has nothing to do with yarn.  it is just that spark is not running in local mode.  it is running distributed.  it has nothing to do with the `yarn-client mode` or the `yarn-cluster mode`.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot tell if this is running in cluster mode or client mode? And
>   why is my setting not getting picked up by the spark UI?

Spark UI running on port 18080 is spark history server. If you want to find which mode your particular application ran in, go to :18080), and click on the any ID under `App ID` which will take you to `Spark Jobs` page.

On that page, click on `Environment` tab. In that tab, look for section `Spark Properties` and under that you will find `spark-master` property which will tell you which mode that application ran in.

Comment: so what does "history server" mean?  and why is that different from what I see in the environment tab.  good tip btw though.

Comment: Well.. Spark WEBUI is usually active as long as your job is running. Once it ends, you cant see information abt that job anymore. But if history server is enabled, it can save all the information which you can view later